# Is heredoc slower than echo in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, performance, shell, heredoc

I am trying to output multiple line string on bash.
In shell script,
is heredoc like
cat << EOF
first line
second line
nth line
EOF
slower than printing each line by using echo?

what is the best way to output multiple line string in shell script?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Here-doc in to `cat` is slower than `echo`, which is a built-in. But a here-doc allows you to pass all characters literally, without worrying about quoting. You can also embed new lines in a quoted argument to `echo`, but any indentation will get printed too. There's also `printf '%s\n' \ line1 \ line2` which can be indented (new lines go after each backslash).

Comment: Concerning your title, there is no such thing as "shell script", so that question doesn't make sense. Please, also reconsider the tags you applied, in particular read their description. That said, "best" is usually asking for opinions, unless clearly specified. Even with your focus on execution speed, I'm wondering how much text you have there and how long it takes. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @dan Thank you. your comment is what I wanted to know. I should have compare the efficiency between cat and echo instead of EOF and echo. But knowing cat is slower than printf and echo discribes my question and solved it. thank you.

Comment: @nxmt You should be aware that the real difference isn't `echo` vs a here-document, it's the number of processes that need to be created to execute the command (none for `echo`, since it's built-in to bash vs one for `cat` because it's external). Comparing `echo "something" | awk 'something'` will be slower than `awk 'something` <<EOF ...` because in this case the `echo` must also run as a separate process.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I did some micro-benchmarks on my laptop

```
for i in $(seq 10000);
do
cat << EOB
first line
second line
third line
EOB
done
```

takes 3.3 sec

```
for i in $(seq 10000);
do
echo "first line
second line
third line"
done
```

takes 40 ms

So echos are probably one hundred time faster than heredocs with cat.

But there are probably very few use cases where you have to do 10 thousands outputs knowing that echos eat double quotes which can be a show stopper for some use case like outputting HTML.

I would go for heredocs and avoid early optimization.

Comment: Two reasons: the heredoc is actually written to a temporary file first, and `cat` is not a shell built-in.

Comment: @chepner, `strace` shows no creation of temporary file using heredoc. BTW I agree on the 'not shell built-in' reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the best of both worlds; you don't need `cat` *or* multiple `echo` commands.

```
 echo "first line
 second line
 third line"
```

You can embed newlines in a word.

Comment: but `echo` eats the double quotes. and sometime, if not very often, double quotes are meaningful in the output.

Comment: `echo` never *sees* the double quotes. The shell removes them while constructing the command line. If you want to display the quotes, you need to escape them.

Comment: yes, this is exactly, with echos, you don't have the best of both worlds since you'll have to escape quotes ; with heredocs, no need for esacping.